# Test state change of a reflux store with mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, refluxjs

I am writing mocha tests against a Reflux store, to validate that an action causes the state within a store to change. The scaled-down version of the code is given below:

**Store:**

```
var AppStore = Reflux.createStore({
  init: function () {
    this.foo = false;
  },
  listenables: [AppActions],
  onFooAction: function() {
    this.foo = !this.foo;
    this.trigger({action: "foo-ed"});
  };
});
```

**Action:**

```
var AppActions = Reflux.createActions([
  "fooAction"
]);
```

**Test:**

```
it("toggles foo", function () {
  expect(AppStore.foo).to.equal(false);

  AppStore.listenables[0].fooAction();

  expect(AppStore.foo).to.equal(true);
});
```

However, the second assertion (`expect(AppStore.foo).to.equal(true);`) fails saying that `foo` is still false.

By performing a `console.log` within the `onFooAction` method, I've verified that the method is actually triggered and `this.foo` is getting toggled.

Is there anything fundamental that I am missing here: conceptually or otherwise? I sincerely hope that it is not a timing issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actions emit events to which the stores listen. Basically, your test is just running too quickly.

Usually, in my tests, I assume that Reflux is going to do what it does correctly, and I call the listener function directly. You'd want to add a few more assertions to make sure that Reflux is wired up correctly.

```
it("is configured", function () {
  expect(AppStore.listenables).to.include(AppActions);
  expect(AppActions.fooAction).to.be.a('function');
});

it("toggles foo", function () {
  expect(AppStore.foo).to.equal(false);

  AppStore.onFooAction();

  expect(AppStore.foo).to.equal(true);
});
```

Another way you could test this is with a timeout, but I feel dirty when I put timeouts inside tests.

```
it("toggles foo", function (done) {
  expect(AppStore.foo).to.equal(false);

  AppStore.listenables[0].fooAction();

  setTimeout(function () {
    try {
      expect(AppStore.foo).to.equal(true);
      done();
    } catch (e) {
      done(e);
    }
  }, 15);
});
```